# How to print all of a bpy.data.object's information?

Tags: python

How can I print all of the information regarding a specific object inside a scene in 2.8? I need to check the size, texture, color, everything, all the properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can type `dir(C.active_object)` in python console to print all properties of currently active object.